# How to debug cordova/phonegap app in windows phone emulator

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone app usign Cordova / Phonegap. I made it work for Android, but now that I'm trying wp for the first time I find myself with some unknown errors (some elements are not getting loaded).

How can I debug my javascript so I can get to know what is going wrong with my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to debug a Windows Cordova/Phonegap app from Visual Studio. When you create your project and then add the Windows platform:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add windows
```

Cordova will create a CordovaApp.sln file in the hello\platforms\windows directory. Open that up in Visual Studio 2013 (or open CordovaApp.vs2012.sln if you have Visual Studio 2012), select the project you want to debug in the Solution Explorer pane, select the emulator you want to run it in in the toolbar (or select Device to run it on an actual device), and then hit F5 to start debugging. You can set breakpoints in your Javascript code just like you would in C# or VB.
[image: Visual Studio Run Menu]

Comment: How can we see web/javascript errors? I can't find any place to see that.

Comment: @MoOx: Errors are displayed in the JavaScript Console window, which is only available when the app is running. From Visual Studio, run the app in an emulator. Once it's running, if the JavaScript Console window does not open automatically, select Debug -> Windows -> JavaScript Console from the main menu or press Ctrl+Alt+V,C to open it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same when you try on a real device? I am testing on a HTC 8s updated to 8.1 and cannot do that, "JavaScript Console" is disabled in the menu...

Comment: Yep, just select "Device" from the dropdown menu in the toolbar (see screenshot above).